# UTF-8 vs ASCII Text

Tags: sql

Why does sql database use UTF-8 Encoding? do they both use 8-bit to store a character?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UTF-8 is used to support a large range of characters. In UTF-8, up to 4 bytes can be used to represent a single character.

Joel has written an article on this subject that you may want to refer to

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

For "normal" characters, only 8 bits are used. For characters that do not fit in 8 bits more bits can be used. This makes UTF-8 is a variable length encoding.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has a good article on UTF-8.

ASCII only defines 128 character. So only 7 bits. But is normally stored with 8 bits/character. RS232 (old serial communication) can be used with bytes of 7 bits.

Comment: The amount of space used depends on the character code.  For some characters, it'll use up to 4 bytes for a single char.  The ones that use that much space aren't in the BMP, though.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII can only represent a limited number of characters at one time.  It isn't very useful to represent any language that isn't based on a Latin character set.  However, UTF-8 which is an encoding standard for UCS-4 (Unicode) can represent almost any language.  It does this by chaining multiple bytes together to represent one character (or glyph to be more correct).

Comment: Isn't it UTF-16 what you are saying?

Comment: What do you mean?  UTF-16 is just another encoding standard.  UTF-7,8,16,32 are all encoding standards that encode UCS-4 (this wasn't always the case, and I wouldn't be shocked if there are still some exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

A more sophisticated encoding increases the index access time drastically. It's something to think about, when encountering performance problems in writing or reading from an database.