# Trademark (™) symbol displayed as ? during marshalling process using JAXB?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jaxb, marshalling

I have a Java object that I need to marshall. One of the attributes on my object has a String description which contains a Trademark symbol (™).

But after when the marshalling is done, it is displayed as a question mark (?). I have played around with the encoding and try to set it to US-ASCII then it returns and display the symbol perfectly.

I googled differences between ASCII and UTF-8 but and it looks like UTF has a larger character set [UTF-8 vs ASCII Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766267/utf-8-vs-ascii-text).

That being said it looks a bit dangerous to go to ASCII from UTF-8 if UTF-8 has a larger character set.

I also looked this [Usages of ASCII and UTF-8](http://w3techs.com/technologies/comparison/en-usascii,en-utf8) and ASCII is used less than 1%.

What is the correct way to encode the ™ using JAXB?

My marshaller to decode it looks as follows:

```
public String marshall(final Response response) {
    final Marshaller marshaller = getContextResponse().createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.FALSE);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    synchronized (responseMarshalMutex) {
       marshaller.marshal(response, writer);
    }
    return writer.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

Comment: I believe the opposite of your statement is true.  Since UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, it is always safe to go from ASCII to UTF-8, because you are guaranteed not to lose any information.  Every character will be preserved.  However, going from UTF-8 to ASCII is dangerous, since any non-ASCII characters would be converted to something like `'?'` (or would generate an exception, depending on how you do the conversion).

Comment: Don't know if my wording is correct but as I stated "dangerous to go to ASCII from UTF-8, if UTF-8 has a larger character set". This does indicate that UTF-8 = (ASCI + more). Or am I missing something :)

Answer (score 2):

When you tell JAXP to use ASCII as the encoding, it will represent any non-ASCII characters using character entities ... such as the (TM) character.  This will pass through a 7-bit channel without damage, and can usually be "safely" decoded with an inappropriate character encoding.

When you tell JAXP to use UTF-8 as the encoding, non-ASCII characters will be encoded as multi-byte sequences, many of which have the top bit set.  If you then attempt (e.g. by accident) at some point to decode that using the wrong encoding, you are liable to get some kind of garbling.  (For example, this might happen if the XML was sent in a HTTP request or reply and you neglected to specify the character encoding in the 'content-type' header.

Given the choice, it is probably better to use ASCII (or Latin-1) as your encoding when you generate the XML.  This will maximize that chance that you will get the same text values when you finally parse the XML.